# Accessing the system .Destructive red button color

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

How do you access the system red color used for the destructive alert button style?

For instance, the default style blue color used for buttons can be accessed in Swift by `let systemBlueColor = view.tintColor`, which corresponds to `UIColor(red: 0, green: 122, blue: 255, alpha: 1.0)`.

The destructive red color seems to be given by `UIColor(red: 255, green: 59, blue: 48, alpha: 1.0)` but is there any way to access it in a similar way to the default `view.tintColor` method?

I have read that RGB interpretations can vary on devices / operating systems, so I would like to access the device / operating system independent version of the color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an undocumented class method on `UIColor` called `_systemDestructiveTintColor` which will return the color you need:

```
let red = UIColor.performSelector("_systemDestructiveTintColor").takeUnretainedValue()
```

It returns an unmanaged object, which you must call `.takeUnretainedValue()` on, since the color ownership has not been transferred to our own object.

As with any undocumented API, you should take caution when trying to use this method:

Swift 5:

```
if UIColor.responds(to: Selector(("_systemDestructiveTintColor"))) {
    if let red = UIColor.perform(Selector(("_systemDestructiveTintColor")))?.takeUnretainedValue() as? UIColor {
        // use the color
    }
}
```

Previous Swift versions:

```
if UIColor.respondsToSelector("_systemDestructiveTintColor") {
    if let red = UIColor.performSelector("_systemDestructiveTintColor").takeUnretainedValue() as? UIColor {
        // use the color
    }
}
```

This and other colors can be found in the UIColor [header](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIColor.h).

Comment: Why `takeRetainedValue()`? Judging from the selector name it should be `takeUnretainedValue()`.

Comment: @MartinR I wasn't sure if this was the get rule or the copy rule,  I guess it's just the get rule.  I'll change my answer to `takeUnretainedValue`.

Comment: @MartinR "You use takeUnretainedValue when ownership of the object has not been transferred to you and you therefore do not want ARC releasing the object for you when it falls out of scope."  Yep you're correct.

Comment: And why a forced cast? (Xcode emits a warning "treating a forced downcast to 'UIColor' as optional will never produce 'nil'".) Does the method return a (unmanaged) `UIColor` or `UIColor?` ?

Comment: @MartinR correct again, no need to force downcast.  I've edited my answer.