# How can I get the default iOS red warning color?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

How can I get the default iOS red warning color that is used in `UIAlertAction` with style `UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive` without composing the color myself?

Comment: Do you need just access and read the color property, or your purpose is to change that color?

Comment: @pedrouan I want to access the color property without instantiating a UIAlertAction.

Comment: You are trying to access that color at runtime? Or just need the color definition?

Comment: @pedrouan I want to access it at runtime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the system .Destructive red button color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139462/accessing-the-system-destructive-red-button-color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API that will allow you to access the color at runtime without creating a `UIAlertAction`.

I know it's not exactly what you wanted, but you can do something like this:

```
extension UIColor {
    class func destructiveColor() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.2196078431, blue: 0.137254902, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let redColor = UIColor.redColor()
let destructiveColor = UIColor.destructiveColor()
```

Note that the two reds are slightly different:

[image]

Of course, this solution is imperfect because it will not automatically update if Apple tweaks the color.

Answer (score 4):

Well, this question interested me and I tried to get this color. The only idea that came with is to create off-screen alert view controller and enumerate its views recursively so I can find needed label or button for destructive action. What surprised me is fact that alert view controller's view contains collection view. However, I couldn't dive deeper into this collection view – it just says that it doesn't contain subviews. This is probably was made by Apple for security purposes, so no one could tap alert button programmatically.

So, my only suggestion – use something like Digital Color meter in OS X to determine that color and then just hardcode it. Looks like there is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

As it goes for many other style properties and definitions in iOS SDK, either **UIAlertActionStyle derives its color - for .destructive style - from the base class, that is private and not publicly accessible.**

There's no way to access that color at runtime without creating an instance of UIAlertAction and looping its subviews.

The only way is to check color manually as Alexander Doloz notes in his answer.